# Efficient bi-directional binding of a control and a property

Tags: delphi, properties, binding, controls

I have a FireMonkey FMX `TForm` in Delphi 10.2 with many `TSpinBoxes`. For each `TSpinBox` I add a corresponding property to the `TForm`.

I want to link each `TSpinBox` to the corresponding `TForm` property so that changing the value of a  `TSpinBox` automatically updates the corresponding `TForm` property and vice versa.

In the past I did this by using an `OnChange` event handler for each `TSpinBox` to update the corresponding `TForm` property and the property's setter method to update the `TSpinBox` value.

Because I have many `TSpinBoxes` this is now becoming very cumbersome. Is there a better, more efficient way to do this?

Comment: It is hard for me to give much useful suggestion because since you haven't shown any code I can just guess of what you are doing. But since you appear to be working with many components of same type you might want to learn on how share one common event handler between multiple components (using `Sender` to determine which component fired the event). Or perhaps how indexed properties work. It might allow you to have a single property for updating state of any of your SpinBoxes. Without seeing pat of your existing code all we can do is just guess. And her on SO such questions are not wanted.